# Spring Cloud Config: differentiate configs for service instances

Tags: config, spring-cloud

Spring Cloud Config serves configuration based on app name, profile and label.
I'm wondering, how to differentiate configuration of two instances of same service on same environment. They should basically have the same configuration, but, for example, I would like to allow on testing environment running them on the same host, so I need different ports.

How you solve this? Using fake profiles (dev-1, dev2)? Or is there some better way?

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility for individual instance configuration as you noted. You could do a fake profile thing. But for port, why not just set `server.port`?

Comment: Thanks for info. I am just checking now, what are the options. So general approach is, for instance specific configs, it cannot/shouldnt be managed through config server, but rather during deployment, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, running multiple instances of the same service on the same machine only makes sense in dev-like environments.